# JPA auto flush before any query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, flush

From JPA documentation I can see that the AUTO is the default flush mode, flush should happen before any query execution. I have tried this on spring boot jpa and I can see the flush won't happen on queries from different entities , is that expected ? even though different entity may have relation to it ( Department <--> Person here )

The flush should trigger before any query according to this article :
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-jpa-and-hibernate-define-the-auto-flush-mode/

```
// this triggers flush //
 Person person = personRepository.findById(5L).get();
 person.setName("hello test");
 Person person1 = (Person) entityManager.createQuery("select person from Person 
 person where person.id=11").getSingleResult(); // flush before query



// this doesn't trigger flush even if  the department has the person //
 Person person = personRepository.findById(5L).get();
 person.setName("hello test");
 Department department= (Department) entityManager.createQuery("select 
 department from Department
department where department.id=1").getSingleResult();
```

---

**Update:**

I noticed the flush happens for JPQL queries on the same table only that has the DML , while for native sql queries it will always flush before any query if there is DML before. even though no flush happens the JPQL return the managed entity with modification not the one in DB. can anyone please explain if this follow JPA standard or not ?

Comment: Read this, there's no better source than Vlad: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-the-auto-flush-work-in-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @Shadov I read that but it's related to hibernate , I'm using jpa and no native query

Comment: @MohammadKarmi JPA is just a specification / a document. Hibernate EclipseLink etcetera are its implementations. You are using hibernate or another provider.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov I know that but JPA does the flush in different way https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-jpa-and-hibernate-define-the-auto-flush-mode/

Comment: @MohammadKarmi well i learned something new today :)

Comment: @MohammadKarmi is your repository a spring-data repository ?

Comment: @MohammadKarmi try using the entitymanager for the first fetch. It would be interesting to eliminate the spring-data from the picture.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov nice suggestion but the same behavior, the flush doesn't trigger until the commit

Answer (score 7):

As JPA is a specification this question is simple to answer. Check out the spec :-)

**3.10.8 Queries and Flush Mode**

The flush mode setting affects the result of a query as follows.
When queries are executed within a transaction, if FlushModeType.AUTO is set on the Query, TypedQuery, or StoredProcedureQuery object, or if the flush mode setting for the persistence context is AUTO (the default) and a flush mode setting has not been specified for the query object, the persistence provider is responsible for ensuring that all updates to the state of all entities in the persistence context which could potentially affect the result of the query are visible to the processing of the
query. The persistence provider implementation may achieve this by flushing those entities to the database or by some other means. If FlushModeType.COMMIT is set, the effect of updates made to entities in the persistence context upon queries is unspecified.

If the persistence context has not been joined to the current transaction, the persistence provider must
not flush to the database regardless of the flush mode setting.

```
package javax.persistence;
public enum FlushModeType {
COMMIT,
AUTO
}
```

If there is no transaction active, the persistence provider must not flush to the database

https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1561799350_4cc62583442da694a6a033af82faf986

**Then there is the Hibernate Doc:**

6.1. AUTO flush

By default, Hibernate uses the AUTO flush mode which triggers a flush in the following circumstances:

- prior to committing a Transaction
- prior to executing a JPQL/HQL query that overlaps with the queued entity actions
- before executing any native SQL query that has no registered synchronization

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing

Comment: do you mean hibernate is following JPA spec because of "The persistence provider implementation may achieve this by flushing those entities to the database or by some other means. " by other means no need to flush just achieve the visibility of the query ?

Comment: Yes sure. I added the section of the hibernate doc

Comment: Thanks that is very useful, last question , in my case the department has relation with person why the flush didn't trigger ? isn't there overlap ?

Comment: Has the person any changes when you query the department?

Comment: Yes , I do set the name before. you can compare the 2 cases above it looks weird why department doesn't need flush , Person is child for it.