# JPA firing INSERT before SELECT during an UPDATE?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring JPA repository that is attempting to do a SELECT on an entity. This entity has a relationship with its parent thus:

> User (Parent ) > Addresses > AddressType (Child)

During the course of updating the `User`, I want to add An `Address`. The Address has a field `addressType` that is OneToOne Relationship with an `AddressType` Static Data Table (Ie the address type can only be `POBOX` or `General`) as depicted above.
During the process of UPDATING `User`, am adding a new `Address` and doing a `findByName` of AddressType with the passed in addressType from the incoming `User+Address` DTO.

However, When I do a `findByName` on AddressType's JPA repository - IT attempts to do an INSERT on the parent `Address` first. What this does is cause a IntegrityViolationException since Address is being first inserted WITHOUT an `AddressType` which is a mandatory field. I did some research here on SO and found some threads indicating this could be a behavior of entitymanager which is somehow declaring the `Address` being added as dirty.

My question is - how can I prevent an INSERT on the parent `Address` so that the SELECT on the `AddressType` happens on its own?

Comment: Don't add Address/User until after you've done the AddressType lookup. Only add something to the PersistenceUnit/Transaction when you are sure it is complete, which it isn't until you have the AddressType reference set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal flushing behaviour of JPA. When you change an entity managed by JPA these changes get flushed to the database before a query gets executed.

You did change a `User` entity by adding an `Address` to it.

To fix that add the `Address` only when it is fully constructed, i.e. it's `AddressType` is set.

*Note: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find it. But there is this closely related question: [JPA auto flush before any query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56812221/jpa-auto-flush-before-any-query)*